# Microsoft Visual J#® 2.0 Redistributable Package for x64 and x86

Tags: .net, x86, 64-bit, j#

Is there a version of **Microsoft Visual J#® 2.0 Redistributable Package** which will support both x86 and x64 platforms?

In the download center, i found only different dlls for both platforms!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Microsoft Visual J#® 2.0 Redistributable Package – Second Edition (x64), we will be able to build dlls with platform target any platform on a 64 bit machine.

It can be downloaded from: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15468

Comment: Your link no longer works, and the official Microsoft site also links to the same (broken) URL:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msdn10/bb188593(v=msdn.10)